# Database distribution dose not exist in sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm creating a dynamic SQL log that will tell me the unpending transaction.

I'm trying to enter `sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds` into a table for that reason in need to execute it as `sp_executesql`.

For some reason when I finish running the script it says

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   Database 'distribution' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

and im running it on distribution database.
Thank you for your help

```
set @counter = 1    
while @counter <@NOR
BEGIN

        select  @v_publisher=servername,
                @v_publisher_db=DbName,
                @v_publication = DbName+'_1way',
                @v_subscriber = @@servername,
                @v_subscriber_db =DbName
        from Serverses
        where id = @counter         

SET @sql = N'SELECT * INTO #pendingcmds 
FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',''SERVER=(LOCAL);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES''
,''SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC distribution.dbo.sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds @publisher=['
+ @v_publisher + '],
@publisher_db='+ @v_publisher_db + ',
@publication='+ @v_publication + ',
@subscriber=['+ @v_subscriber + '],
@subscriber_db='+ @v_subscriber_db + ',
@subscription_type=' + CONVERT(CHAR(1),@pubtype) + ''')'
select @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql 


            set @counter=@counter+1

END
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it that way. When you run that dynamic query you are in a context and even the openrowset ill take trouble to change that to run at that remote server. Cannot you use EXEC AT to execute the dynamic at the remote server?

Comment: Also instead of doing this dynamic query cannot you create a SP at the remote server and just call it?

Comment: My goal is to insert the EXEC sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds into a table